# In VB.NET does MS require the fully qualified function name for the Right or Left string functions?

Tags: vb.net, string

According to the Microsoft documentation, to determine the number of characters in str, use the Len function. If used in a Windows Form, or any other class that has a Right property, you must fully qualify the function with "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right".

If I set "Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic" at the top of the form I still have to use the fully qualified name in my code.  Why does MS require this?

Comment: What version of VB.NET are you using?  I am unable to confirm your findings using VB.NET 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, without the fully qualified name, if there are two methods with the same name, the compiler cannot choose one over the other. So you should take care of the problem giving the correct hint

To ease your typing you could add at the top of your code file this version of the [Imports statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx)

```
Imports VB6 = Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

and then you could type

```
Dim stringLen = VB6.Len(yourStringVariable)
```

[This is the MSDN introduction to Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx) in VB.NET, in particular, in the first lines of the article is explained your problem **Avoiding Namespaces Collisions**

> NET Framework namespaces address a problem sometimes called namespace
>   pollution, in which the developer of a class library is hampered by
>   the use of similar names in another library. These conflicts with
>   existing components are sometimes called name collisions.
>
> For example, if you create a new class named ListBox, you can use it
>   inside your project without qualification. However, if you want to use
>   the .NET Framework ListBox class in the same project, you must use a
>   fully qualified reference to make the reference unique. If the
>   reference is not unique, Visual Basic produces an error stating that
>   the name is ambiguous.

And by the way, start to use the equivalent framework methods for Right, Left, and Len. 
They are still available only to help the porting of old VB6 application, (and sometime they work differently). In new applications I suggest to use

```
string.Substring(start, len)
string.Length
```

Answer (score 1):

A winform, `Form` (derived from `Control`), have properties named `Right` and `Left`.

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub Test()

        Dim location_left As Integer = Me.Left
        Dim location_right As Integer = Me.Right

        'Or simply:

        location_left = Left '<- (Referring to Me.Left, not Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left)
        location_right = Right '<- (Referring to Me.Right, not Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Therefore you'll need the use the full qualify name.